# Would it be viable to run an AP champ in bottom lane with a support and put your ranged AD carry in mid?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that the current meta is AP champ in mid with AD carry with support in bottom lane but I have thought about the potential of switching that up.

Keep in mind that I think this would only work as purple team because the AP champ in bottom lane would want to be able to get blue.

Here is an example team composition:

**AP Bottom: Cassiopeia, Swain, or Morgana.**  Picking an AP champ that can push and farm with some ease.  It would be very important for this champ to run **flat armor yellows** and maybe even an armor quint.  The idea would be to push the lane and try to force the enemy AD to lose cs by farming at tower.

**Bottom Support: Soraka.**  Soraka would allow the AP champ to spam their spells even when they don't have blue.  It would also allow for the lane to have a lot of sustain and be relatively safe.

**AD Carry Mid: Tristana or Graves. **  Picking someone with some form of escape is important here.  The rune page should have flat magic resist blues to help with trading damage.  Having someone like Tristana who has a lot of range should be able to easily force the enemy champ out of lane.

I think there would be an advantage when trading damage because the enemy champion will be running the wrong runes (Magic resistance vs Attack damage and Armor vs Magic damage).  This could potentially turn into getting an early lane advantage.  If you are on purple side your AP champ in bot lane could still get blue and be able to push and farm well.  With good warding a champion like Cassiopeia could safely keep the lane pushed up to tower with a Soraka support and the help of blue buff.

Could this work in competitive play?  Duo Q (with the duo playing as the AP and AD champs)?

Comment: I think this can work but the mid AD Carry needs to have some kind of escape ability ( like Tristana ), because in my opinoin the problem is if he's facing some kind of Burst Champion like Ahri/Kassadin/Akali in mid. Because when they reach Lvl 6 they could pose a real thread to some squishy carry (like Ashe) , which cant escape their ganks.

Comment: The trouble is with this meta, you don't have the assassins mid, burst AP champs like Kassadin, Kat, Ahri they are great mid because top and bot lanes are open to them. If Ahri for example is bot, she can almost never go top. Visa versa, if the AD carry doesn't have any advantage of leveling faster then why do it?

Comment: Short answer: ADCs aren't normally very self sufficient.  This used to be the normal meta when LoL first came out because people would often do this sort of thing in DotA 1.  When the meta was being formed, this was pretty quickly pushed out for the simple fact that ADCs don't scale well with levels.  They need items and a babysitter.  APCs scale great with levels and are extremly self sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

**Generally speaking? No, probably not.**

Mostly because AP characters value levels over items in most cases, and in bot lane you'd be having a support sucking up XP. Overall, this would mean that the enemy's AP carry in mid is becoming stronger than the AP character in bottom lane, while the allied AD carry in mid isn't becoming notably stronger than the enemy AD carry at bot. AD carries scale with items, and not really with levels. Thus, the AD carry wouldn't really gain anything from being in mid lane.

The majority of AD carries also couldn't lane against the majority of AP carries. While AD carries would start off strong, with decent pokes, once the AP carry gets to level 6 and has a Doran's Ring or two it is pretty much game over unless they've fed. There is no way an AD carry can keep up with the raw control and damage of an AP mid. Regardless of who the mid is.

The only exceptions to the above rule would be Corki, Ezreal, and possibly Urgot. Corki actually does scale with levels, as does Ezreal to an extent. Urgot is just innately tanky with super long ranged harass. ALL of those characters would have mana issues though, and would have to rush a mana regen item to compensate for that. And Corki and Ezreal would still have trouble with high burst/high CC champions such as Cassio/Annie/Ahri/Karthus/Just About Every Popular AP Mid Right Now.

**Specifically speaking? Sure!**

There will always be specific situations where you could counter certain champion picks by using more elaborate strategies. This is where a lot of the original "meta breaking" strategies come from. Such as running kill lanes in bot, double AP carries, double AD carries, or even double jungle. It can work in certain situations, but it won't work on a regular basis. And will rarely if ever work in solo or duo ques.

Comment: And now Mordekaiser gets more Exp in duo lanes =)

Answer (score 2):

This **works** in competitive play.

I already saw it winning on pro streams several times.

Also a big advantage is that its possible to simply switch lanes if its not working out as planned!

Also a nice champ for bot would be Karthus.

And for mid i would pick a high range carry so you can easily harass. (Caitlyn/Ashe) 
BTW Ashe mid was a part of the meta some time ago. (if i remember correctly)

Comment: I thought about Ashe but I would be worried about her getting ganked a lot early on.  She is slow and doesn't have any escapes.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Pugzebub yes Ashe was more a honorable mention from the old time, you know back then when caitlyn didn't exist.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment above I still think it also depends on the enemy mid lane champion. Some AP Carrys have the only role to shut down the squishys ( -> so the AD Carry ) from your team. So if you're facing such burst monsters on lane I think you could get in some troubles if you don't have great escape abilities such as Tristanas Jump.

Comment: Yes sure. But as i mentioned you Can just switch lanes in such situations. Or avoid them in draft selection; you shouldnt try to force such a composition IMO.

Comment: Yes I agree with Patrick.  It won't come up all that often as you need to be red team and facing the right champions.  It shouldn't be forced.

Comment: Would Sivir be a viable choice for middle lane? She has long range farm and harass with her boomerang and ricochet, a spell sheild to block damage, and her ultimate to give her movement speed to escape from ganks.

Comment: @AndrewHenry Escape Not very viable but spell shield is very strong against high cd characters (e.g. veigar). Harass/damage trading medioker due low range and damage reduction on boomerang when passing through creeps. But generally shes ok(kinda viable) But i would prefer other Champions if possible.

Comment: Her spell shield and Ultimate can be very effective against certain junglers - a well timed spell shield will block a dangerous ultimate, and then her own ultimate is like a low cool down Ghost to allow her to escape. But why would young bring Sivir when Zed has just as much poke, and a better escape to go along with it?

Answer (score 0):

**AP bot vs AD bot**

You probably do not want to do this is duo que because your team may not be ready for it.
Are all people comfortable with the switch?

When you fight for creep score, after you trade blows, your AP will usually have a high CD on their skills.  This means that the only way to harass is with auto attacks and the AD will win that battle.  Now the AD can out farm you by keeping you out of the battle.

So you would have to use a low CD character like Cassiopeia.  Her skills are skill shots (which are hard to miss), and now all she has to worry about his her mana.  She could run mana runes/items but that will gimp her damage.  The AD doesn't have to use mana items (usually) and can focus on damage (graves).

If your mana regeneration can keep up with your mana usage, it may be viable to sustain damage as the AD.  But then again, how much can you put into your damage as AP?

**Your support**

Don't count on using soraka as a support.  She will be able to give your AP character some mana but then she loses her other ability as well.  Where if soraka was with an AD she could use her silence instead of mana.  What if the other team got soraka and could shutdown your AP??